# SyntaxError: expected expression, got ''

Tags: javascript, php

I know there are many questions with this same title, but all I've seen do not apply to my problem.

I currently have a PHP function that looks like this:

```
function mostraFraseStatus($i, $f){
        print'document.getElementById("cliente'.$i.'").innerHTML = "<span style=\'color:#FF0000\'>'.$f.'</span>";';
    }
```

Within the validations, it is executed this way:

```
} else {
                        mostraFraseStatus($idProdutoSelecionado, "Text Here");
                    }
```

It works normally, but I need to change that `print` to an `alert`. I have tried the following:

```
function mostraFraseStatus($i, $f){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Test');</script>";
    }
```

However I am getting the title error while executing the function by the navigator: **SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'**

How can I fix it?

Comment: no closing `</script>`

Comment: I have tested without closing and closing, it does not work. :/

Comment: Are you trying to add a script tag into a script tag? If the first one works, you just need to `alert('$f');` it

Comment: Are you able to provide any additional information, such as where on the page your content is being `echo`'d? From just running your example code, it works correctly for me.

Comment: @Jacin The code is confusing, it fires when I click a button with the onclick property.

Comment: @zecaluis I agree with @ThumChoonTat that you may be `echo`ing <script> tags inside an existing <script> block

Comment: @JacinTattersall Not sure if it is not going to work? Do you have any alternatives? I tested that way the did not work either: `alert('teste');`

Comment: @zecaluis In that case, it is going to be difficult to diagnose the issue without more information about the environment that the code is being output to. I wouldn't worry about the code being confusing. This is stack overflow and confusing code is 99% of what gets posted

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, that was really the problem. It was not working because I forgot to put the echo before, it looked like this: `echo "alert('$f')";` If you want to respond with the solution I mark the question as answered, I do not know how it works now. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely caused by `echo`'ing a `<script>` block inside an existing `<script>` block. Simply change your code like so:

```
function mostraFraseStatus($i, $f){
    echo "alert('Test');";
}
```